# how to calculate row by row value till to every 60 minutes in same column using python

Tags: python, time

Here I have a dataset with time and value. So here I want to sum the value row by row in every 60 minutes.

```html
date           x
8/6/2018 6:15 0
8/6/2018 6:20 2.89295
8/6/2018 6:25 2.89295
8/6/2018 6:30 2.89295
8/6/2018 6:35 2.89295
8/6/2018 6:40 2.89295
8/6/2018 6:45 2.89295
8/6/2018 6:50 2.89295
8/6/2018 6:55 2.89295
8/6/2018 7:00 2.89295
8/6/2018 7:05 2.89295
8/6/2018 7:10 2.89295
8/6/2018 7:15 2.89295
8/6/2018 7:20 2.89295
8/6/2018 7:25 2.89295
8/6/2018 7:30 2.89295
8/6/2018 7:35 2.89295
8/6/2018 7:40 2.89295
8/6/2018 7:45 3.155946
8/6/2018 7:50 3.155946
8/6/2018 7:55 3.155946
8/6/2018 8:00 3.155946
8/6/2018 8:05 3.155946
8/6/2018 8:10 3.155946
8/6/2018 8:15 3.155946
```

expected output is :

Here I want add each and value in every five minutes value sum it till to 60 minutes 60 minutes.

means:

```html
date           x              new_x
8/6/2018 6:15 0                0
8/6/2018 6:20 2.89295          2.89295
8/6/2018 6:25 2.89295          2.89295 +  2.89295   =   5.7859 
8/6/2018 6:30 2.89295          2.89295 +  2.89295 + 2.89295 = 8.67885
8/6/2018 6:35 2.89295          2.89295 +  2.89295 + 2.89295 + 2.89295 = 11.5718
8/6/2018 6:40 2.89295
8/6/2018 6:45 2.89295           like wise till to one hour 
8/6/2018 6:50 2.89295  
8/6/2018 6:55 2.89295
8/6/2018 7:00 2.89295
8/6/2018 7:05 2.89295
8/6/2018 7:10 2.89295
8/6/2018 7:15 2.89295         2.89295 +  2.89295 + 2.89295 + 2.89295+........=   34.7154  
8/6/2018 7:20 2.89295         2.89295 (after one hour then again another hour , so
                                       then again value will be 2.89295)
                                       it will depend on the value at that time)
```

I don't know how to do sum it with that increasing value. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to see if this was possible using Pandas [Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) and Cumulative Sum function, however, I could not find a way. Its possible with a hard boundary at end of the hour for eg. if you wanted to reset the sum at 7:00 rather than 7:15, but not like you wanted. May be someone can suggest on those lines. Meanwhile a simple solution with lot of Python code.

I have put some comments inline to help you understand this, also this assumes you are holding your data in a DataFrame and the Date column is set as Date not string. You might need to convert strings to date in the loop below otherwise.

```
#Get the first Date and hold its reference
lastDate = dataset.iat[0,0]
#Initialize the sum to 0
cumulativeSum = 0
for i in dataset.index:
    #Find the time difference between this row and the last held Date
    dateDiff = dataset.at[i, 'Date'] - lastDate
    if dateDiff.total_seconds() > 3600:
        #If the difference is more than 60Min then we reset the sum also hold this date as the last reference date
        cumulativeSum = 0
        lastDate = dataset.at[i, 'Date']
    #Add the current value to cumulative sum and store it in our new field
    cumulativeSum = cumulativeSum + dataset.at[i, 'Value']
    dataset.at[i, 'NewX'] = cumulativeSum
print(dataset)
```